# Autobahn android exception RSV != 0 and no extension negotiated

Tags: android, tomcat, websocket, autobahn

I want create long polling connection in Android. I'm use library - Autobahn. 
Void startpolling i'm call in OnCreate Activity:

```
private void startPolling() {

          final String wsuri = "ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8084/free";

          try {
             mConnection.connect(wsuri, new WebSocketHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onOpen() {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Status: Connected to " + wsuri);
                   mConnection.sendTextMessage("Hello, world!");
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextMessage(String payload) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Got echo: " + payload);
                }

                @Override
                public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Connection lost.");
                }
             });
          } catch (WebSocketException e) {

             Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
          }
       }
```

WebServer Apache Tomcat 8.0.3.0

```
ServerEndpoint("/free")
public class WebSocketPolling {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Resource
    WebServiceContext webServiceContext;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session){
        System.out.println("onOpen");
        session.addMessageHandler(new MessageHandler.Whole<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String message) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm gettin next exception in client code:

```
10-03 12:36:52.370: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(5539): run() : WebSocketException (de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketException: RSV != 0 and no extension negotiated)
10-03 12:36:52.753: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection(5539): opening handshake received
10-03 12:36:52.760: D/TMS:QrRecognitionActivity(5539): Status: Connected to ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8084/free
10-03 12:36:52.760: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection(5539): fail connection [code = 4, reason = WebSockets protocol violation
10-03 12:36:52.760: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketReader(5539): quit
10-03 12:36:52.760: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketWriter(5539): ended
10-03 12:36:52.760: D/MainActivity(5539): Connection lost.
10-03 12:36:52.760: D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection(5539): worker threads stopped
```

Upd. I'm tryed add info in web.xml:

```
<servlet-name>wsChat</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.pop.server.WebSocketPolling
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>wsChat</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/free</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

did not affect...

Comment: did you find solution